# How to list all records from start of the year until the END of last month in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date

So I want to get the records from the beginning of the current year until the end of last month, so not simply -30. I have done the following, but the issue is that it only includes records from the first day of last month (01-07-2015).

```
SELECT start_date,customer_code, "value", quantity
FROM dw_mysql."Vouchers"
WHERE start_date BETWEEN date_trunc('year', now()) AND
    date_trunc('month', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 months';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT start_date,customer_code, "value", quantity
FROM dw_mysql."Vouchers"
WHERE start_date BETWEEN date_trunc('year', now()) AND
    (date_trunc('MONTH', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date
```

The second `date_trunc` term takes the current time at month precision, which is the start of the *current* month, and then subtracats one day from it to get the *last* day of the previous month.

Comment: I think your second argument should be `(date_trunc('MONTH', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 day')::date` but otherwise, yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking...